# Flutter bottom of sliverappbar let 1 pixel of background

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliverappbar

I have a small problem where a 1 pixel bar is sometimes displayed in my header as you can see on the image below.

My code is below. The first function is just to calculate the scroll for the user to have a beautiful animation.
the 1 pixel is surrounded in blue.
i'll be very proud if someone can resolve this problem ^^'...

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_share/flutter_share.dart';

class _CustomHeaderState extends State<CustomHeader> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  double heightHeader = 0;
  _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      double calcul2 = 2 / ((300 - kToolbarHeight) / _scrollController.offset);
      if (calcul2 < 0 && heightHeader != 0) {
        setState(() {
          heightHeader = 0;
        });
      } else if (calcul2 > 2 && heightHeader != 2) {
        setState(() {
          heightHeader = 2;
        });
      } else if (calcul2 >= 0 && calcul2 <= 2) {
        if (heightHeader != calcul2) {
          setState(() {
            heightHeader = calcul2;
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // extendBody: true,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            primary: true,
            pinned: true,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            title: Text(""),
            // elevation: 0,
            expandedHeight: 300,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: widget.image,
            ),
            actions: [//header changed when scroll],
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 0),
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                height: heightHeader >= 1.75 ? 25 - ((heightHeader - 1.75) * 100) : 25,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(25),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: widget.child,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after days of works on this problem, i adopted a new solution with no sliverappbar finally and it works perfectly !
i've just made a stack with two positionned in.
the first one just show a singlechildscrollview with a padding and the second is the header who appears on scroll.

thxs for all contributors !

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Native Device Status Bar ?

If so, then import services first

`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

and then add this to the main Function

`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])`

Comment: i've edited to surround the problem in blue sry ^^'

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are setting an image height with decimals and that is causing that extra pixel being drawn. Try setting the height with `.floorToDouble()`